# Removing bounty on lack of improvement

Tags: feature-request, reputation, bounties

I placed a bounty on one of my SO questions yesterday. Up until now it didn't exactly improve the quality of the current answer. Nor did new answers get posted.

That made me wonder if it would be an idea to be able to remove the bounty, if the bounty period has expired and no additional information was added. Make the juice worth the squeeze.

To add, a bounty in the wild west was only paid when the person with the bounty on his head was killed or brought in. In other words, the bounty was only paid if the payer was satisfied.

#### Pros

- No reputation is lost
- You can place the bounty again on a later time
- Bounty reputation is awarded to the people who deserve it

#### Cons

- More bounties will be placed
- Placing a bounty could have less effect

Comment: The bounty popup has a clear "(this reputation is deducted immediately and cannot be refunded)". Think of it as placing an ad - you don't get your money back even if the ad didn't perform as expected.

Comment: @Oded That's exactly what I'm asking. Is it an idea to change that policy to: No answers? Reputation back.

Comment: All you provided is an idea - no pros or cons. Can you add those? Or at least *why* you think this should happen? As in - something to discuss.

Comment: @Oded I updated the question

Comment: "rep lost for no reason" is not accurate, you paid with reputation to have your question ***featured***, instead of having it packed with the rest of regular questions. Don't want to lose rep? Don't feature it...

Comment: What's to stop everyone offering a bounty on all of their questions and never awarding it? You're suggesting a process that's easily open to abuse.

Comment: @RobertLongson Fair point - I'd like to post an adjusted version of my idea in the future wherein the reputation, if not awarded just disappears.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think a lot of you will agree that watching your reputation counter tick up - knowing that your answers are appreciated by the community - fills most of us with pride.

So when you put those hard-earned points up as a reward, it's supposed to

a) Attract attention, and

b) Mean that you've got skin in the game

**Adding the ability to remove the bounty is dishonest in my opinion.**

1) It has served its purpose of attracting attention to your question, and

2) People have spent more time considering it/answering it than they might have otherwise

Taking those points back is a slap in the face for every person who bothered to reply.

Furthermore, there's a danger associated with removing the cost factor for the person placing the bounty. People might start offering wild bounties in order to attract attention, with no intention of rewarding the points to anyone.

For all these reasons, I think that's a bad idea.

Funny that this should be my first post on Meta.

Comment: What you are saying is exactly my point. What if the bounty hasn't served it's purpose at all. What if it didn't drew any attention? What if the bounty was useless and you have to award it to the only existing answer which is a bad one?

Comment: @Peter - then it's just bad luck? Or maybe add the ability to INCREASE IT, and prolong the deadline? But not remove.

Comment: Increasing the bounty might be an idea

Answer (score 4):

I could see some merit in letting someone remove a bounty that they've cast by paying the amount of the bounty's original value again.  It would allow people to remove a bounty that they feel is being harmful, or where they *strongly* feel that the posted answers aren't deserving of the bounty, but would have enough of a cost to prevent abusive bountiers from not awarding bounties to quality answers.

Comment: Exactly my point. If a bounty does not serve it's purpose, give the ability to undo the bounty. Even if this means not getting your reputation back.

Comment: @Peter My answer states that you'd need to *pay* to revoke the bounty (equal to the amount of the bounty); you don't get to just revoke it for free.